# WPF - How do I get scollviewer to act proeprly?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview

I have a grid, and within that grid I have the following:

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <TabItem Header="Weapons">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <DataGrid>
                ...
            </DataGrid>
         </ScrollViewer>
     </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

So, I have obviously taken out the stuff which isn't needed to show my problem. When the Datagrid fills up, the space it requires obviously grows. I intended this to fill down as far as it could go, and then the scrollviewer would do the rest. However, it seems to think it can have unlimited length, and the scrollviewer never actually scrolls.

I dont want to manually set a maxheight value, as there is moving content above the TabControl so it would change (plus window resizing etc). How would I get the scrollviewer to not expand further than the limits of the window / the parent grid to TabControl?

Condensed "full" xaml:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">

    <Image Source="{StaticResource EmptySlot}" Margin="0" Width="34"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding AuraSlot, FallbackValue={StaticResource AuraSlot}}" Margin="0" Width="34"/>
</Grid>

<Popup AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Relative" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowName}" IsOpen="{Binding WeaponTooltipOpen}" HorizontalOffset="{Binding WeaponOffsetX}" VerticalOffset="{Binding WeaponOffsetY}" PopupAnimation="Fade" OpacityMask="White" >
    ...
</Popup>

<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">

    <Expander orizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Expander.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Equipment Slots" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Expander.Header>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            ...
        </Grid>

    </Expander>
</Grid>

<TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <TabItem Header="Weapons">
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" >
                <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedWeapons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" AlternationCount="2" RowHeaderWidth="0">
                    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            ...
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        ...
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                ...
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

                </DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>


</TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `DG` uses `ScrollViewer` inside its `ItemsPanel`. You code doesn't make much sense, because even if scrolling will work, scroll down will make `DG` column headers invisible. The problem is elsewhere - may be, it will be better to post minimal markup, which reproduces this behavior (the one you've posted doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

If you need vertical scrollbar try this or change to horizontalScrollBar. And CanContentScroll Property to true.

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <TabItem Header="Weapons">
       <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  CanContentScroll="True">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <GridView>
                ...
                </GridView>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
     </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

try if it works, or update me back.

Just try using it With window height if you want of the size of window. it will expand till it gets to the size of window.

Comment: Tried this, Didn't work, sorry. Gave the same effect as before.

Comment: Scroll viewer by default has the property to grow indefinitely if you dont specify the size, once you specify size and can content scroll property true, it will do the trick.

Comment: Would there be a different way to not have to specify the size, but allow it to expand until it reaches the limits of the window / container and then strarts to scroll?

Comment: i have edited my answer and try with putting your window size as the size to grow and then let it scroll. hope it works for you.

Comment: Try using it with window height? Where would I put that, MaxHeight for the scrollviewer? If so, wont work. The scrollviewer doesnt take up the entire height of the window, only some of it.

Comment: so you must have grids that is dividing the total window height, it will grow upto that size only. But as per your query to get the scroll viewer scroll bar that is resolved I hope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83548/discussion-between-deshdeep-singh-and-matthew-parker).